# I have an email signature using HTML and the image not loading correctly

Tags: html, icons, loading

Hi I am trying to make an outlook signature. I got the table made and struggled. It is now trying to load the image from a local file instead of the web link I am pointing it to for the icon. Can someone help? I am sure I messed something up.

My code was slightly longer than the max length so I had to put it in a just paste it link.

https://justpaste.it/3mgsj

Answer (score 0):

change the images tag source

```html
 <v:imagedata src="http://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/sig-logo.png" o:title="test"/>
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am sorry but I am very new to HTML and it is really outside my job function.

Comment: Looks like removing o:title="test" from it got it to load. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I found some documentation on it on Microsoft's site that helped me out.

Comment: hopefully you can chose my answer as the correct one . I will be thankful for that :) peace!